# PHP SQL fetch repite 4 veces el mismo resultado

Tags: php, sql

Uso esta sentencia:

```
$skills = $SQL->query('SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table1.account_id <> table2.account_id LIMIT 10')->fetchAll();
```

Pero cuando uso `print_r($skills);` para ver los datos arrojados, me aparece que cada dato se repite más de 4 veces en distintos arrays.

Comment: Parece un problema asociado a la consulta, al hacer un inner join por cada coincidencia entre tablas tendrás una repetición, es probable que necesites agrupar en algún modo los resultados, para poder contestarte con seguridad sería necesario ver un ejemplo de ambas tablas.

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo aplicando algunos cambios a la consulta y añadiendo otras más. Gracias!